# Can we conclude that Cyclic Quadrilaterals if and only if The radius of the circle surrounding the triangle obtained by dividing a quadrilateral.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I want to know if a square has a circle around it, then we divide the square into two triangles. I want to know Cyclic Quadrilaterals if and only if The radius of the circle surrounding the triangle  obtained by dividing a quadrilateral it true or false and If I know that the circles encircling these two triangles ABC and ACD have the same circle radius, can we assume that there is a circle circling the quadrilateral ABCD And what do we have to support?
[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

It's false. Consider rhombus with angles $60^\circ \text{ and } 120^\circ$